# Versioning ardalis api endpoints

Tags: asp.net, ardalis-cleanarchitecture

I would like to ask..

(Questions are directly directed to StackOverflow: https://github.com/ardalis/ApiEndpoints/issues/new/choose)

Is there any good way versioning ardalis api endpoints?

Default documentation suggests to store route in Request as constant, but that doesnt leverage `ApiVersion` attribute for `ControllerBase`.

Endpoint is `ControllerBase`, but I am unsure how should I mix `ApiVersion` tag with route stored as constant. I dont really want to create some kind of anti pattern.

(I am using cleanArch tag, since I dont have 1500 rep to create new tag [ardalis-api-endpoints])